# Simplified anarchy "if statement"

Tags: php

Is there a way to code this function/executable..

```
if($img1 > "") 
{ 
$show = $img1; 
}
elseif($img2 > "") 
{ 
$show = $img2; 
}
elseif($img3 > "") 
{ 
$show = $img3; 
}
else
{
$show = 'default.jpg';
}
echo $show;
```

..in a more simple way? Thx.

Comment: Yes....there is. Use a `switch`

Comment: @JayBlanchard Please, do tell.

Comment: Did you mean this, `if(imgX != ""){ ...`?

Comment: @Rajdeep Paul Yes, that might do also!

Comment: The OP cannot use a switch because of different variable names: $img1, $img2 etc...

Comment: Any time you end up using variables named 1,2,3,etc it means you should be using an array.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard Thx Ill check it out. :)

Comment: If what you want is "simple", then it doesn't get any simpler than a set of if/elseif/else statements. There is no magic or guessing in what you are doing there. If what you want is better, then do what Devon is suggesting and use a structure that allows you to loop over and get a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you end up using variables named 1,2,3,etc it means you should be using an array.

If you had it like this, for example:

```
$img = [
1=> '',
2=> '',
3=> 'image.jpg'
];
```

You could then process this like so:

```
// Remove empty values
$img = array_filter($img);
// Echo the first value found (image.jpg)
echo current($img);
```

Or to add your default:

```
echo (count($img)) ? current($img) : 'default.jpg';
```

This uses a ternary operator to echo 'default.jpg' if `count($img)` is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Did not test, but something like this:

```
<?php

$img1 = 'hello';
$img2 = 'world';

$array = [1,2,3];
for($i=1; $i<count($array); $i++){
    $v = ${"img{$i}"};
    if( !empty($v) ){
        $show = $v;
        break;
    }
}
echo $show;
```

No idea what you're trying to accomplish or why the code looks like that, seems poorly constructed from the get-go.

Comment: close, but you need something like `${"img".$i}`.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanKuhn fixed, this is ugly code, OP should find a better way.

Comment: I know its badly constructed that is WHY I asked this question. What I am trying to achieve now I will explain in the main question.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the id number of the image, you could do something like this:

```
<?php
$images = array(
'myimg.jpg',
'my_awesome_img.jpg',
'awesome_awesome.jpg'
);

$show = $images[$x];
?>
```

Comment: if they knew the index number, they would know which `$imgX` to display. What they are trying to do is find the index (which in this case is the same as the unknown `X` in their variable).

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```
if(!empty($img1)) { 
  echo $img1; 
} elseif(!empty($img2)) { 
  echo $img2; 
} elseif(!empty($img3)) { 
  echo $img3; 
} else {
  echo 'default.jpg';
}
```

given that you only ever want to display one of these.

Comment: how is this any different or succinct than their current code? Both `$img1 > ''` and `!empty($img1)` would return true if the string is not empty. They are asking for a better way to do it, not the same.